# how to get the image name when click on edit button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

when I get the uploaded image name then getting an error see console

I upload the image successfully in database but now I want to get the uploaded image name when click on the edit button

student.cs

```
namespace AxInMvc.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    
    public partial class student
    {

       public int studentid { get; set; }
       public string studentname { get; set; }
       public string studentimage { get; set; }
```

HomeController.cs

```
        public JsonResult GetbyID(int studentid)
        {
            return Json(InsAjaxEntities.students.FirstOrDefault(x => x.studentid == studentid), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Index.cshtml

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="studentname"><strong>StudentName:</strong></label>
    <input type="text" id="studentname" class="form-control" />
</div>


<div class="form-group">
  <label for="studentimage"><strong>StudentImage:</strong></label>
  <input id="studentimage" type="file" name="file"/>
</div>


@section scripts {
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    function getbyID(studentid) {

            debugger

            $.ajax({

                type: "GET",
                url: "/Home/GetbyID" + "?" + "studentid=" + studentid,
                contentType: "application/json;charset=UTF-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (result) {

                    debugger

                    $('#studentid').val(result.studentid);
                    $('#studentname').val(result.studentname);

                    $('#studentimage').val(result.studentimage); //I think here I am getting error here
                    
                    $('#myModal').modal('show'); //here I am get the data and then updating the data
                    $('#btnUpdate').show();
                    $('#btnAdd').hide();

                },
                error: function (errormessage) {
                    debugger
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(errormessage));

                }
            });
        }
```

when I get the uploaded image name then give an error:

[https://i.stack.imgur.com/ssUug.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cEspG.png)

help please?

Answer (score 0):

Your `<input>` is of `type="file"`:

```
<input id="studentimage" type="file" name="file"/>
```

As the error states, the browser will not allow you to set any value here other than an empty string.  So this operation fails:

```
$('#studentimage').val(result.studentimage);
```

Which makes sense when you step back and think about it.  You have a file *on the server* in your data, but an `<input type="file">` doesn't read the *server's* file system, it reads the *client's* file system.  Which is something you don't have access to from within your web application.

(Also, imagine an internet where you *could* set this to a file that is likely to exist on a user's computer, such as common system files.  Any website you visit would be able to automatically grab files from your computer without your knowledge.  This would be a very bad thing.)

You can display the file you have to the user, such as an image thumbnail or something of that nature.  And you can present the user with an `<input type="file">` to submit a new file, but you can't populate that input with the file you already have.

Basically just remove that line of JavaScript so that you're not attempting to populate that input.